# Background-size transition not work in Chrome

Tags: css, css-transitions, transition, background-size

I'm trying to transition `background-size` and `background-color`.

- **Chrome**: Transition of `background-size` not working
- **Firefox**: Both are working fine

I have also created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lp787z1/1/).

```css
.highlight {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  /*min-height: 800px;*/
  min-height: 200px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*padding-top: 200px;*/
  padding-top: 80px;
  /*background-size: cover;*/
}
.highlight:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  content: "";
}
.highlight {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: auto 110%;
  background-position: center center;
  -moz-transition: background-size 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-size 3s ease;
  transition: background-size 3s ease;
}
.highlight:hover {
  background-size: auto 130%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-transition: background-size 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-size 3s ease;
  transition: background-size 3s ease;
}
.highlight:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  transition: background-color 3s ease;
}
.highlight:hover:before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  transition: background-color 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="highlight" style="background-image:url(http://cdn2.stillgalaxy.com/ori/2015/06/06/female-doctors-stock-photos-2331433563559.jpg);">
</div>
```

Anybody helps me with this? Or can figure that is broking these transition?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect that this because the bg image isn't in the CSS...but rather an inline style.

Comment: Of course it is :) You can check the snippet in firefox.

Comment: @Paulie_D I tried with the background-size in the css too and not work in Chrome, Anyway I need use the background-img in the code

Comment: You can't animate (at least you shouldn't be able to) to/from `auto`...you have to use a value.

Comment: you can use `transform:scale()`, works better in chrome

Comment: @Paulie_D You are right! I change the auto properties and work fine. If you want make a answer I will vote it

Comment: @user1422434 Answer given as requested. TY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why this is not working is that `background-size` is not animatable (or at least shouldn't be) when using a keyword such as `cover`, `contain` or `auto`.

[**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) Explains further:

> **Animatable**: yes, as a repeatable list of , a simple list of , a length, percentage or calc(); when both values are lengths, they are interpolated as lengths; when both values are percentages, they are interpolated as percentages; otherwise, both values are converted into a calc() function that is the sum of a length and a percentage (each possibly zero), and these calc() functions have each half interpolated as real numbers. **This means keyword values are not animatable**.

So, adjust the original/final values to be actual numbers (or lengths as they are more properly referred to) and you'll resolve this one.

Comment: You are right :) I had this working some time ago, maybe latest Chrome updates change their behaivour

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform: scale(1.3)` and `transition: all` to achieve the background size transition effect.

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0Lp787z1/2/).

**Note**: I have also added an **wrapper** to hide the overflow.

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.highlight {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  /*min-height: 800px;*/
  min-height: 200px;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  /*padding-top: 200px;*/
  padding-top: 80px;
  /*background-size: cover;*/
}
.highlight:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .25);
  content: "";
}
.highlight {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-size: auto 110%;
  background-position: center center;
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
.highlight:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-transition: all 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 3s ease;
  transition: all 3s ease;
}
.highlight:before {
  content: ' ';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  -moz-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  transition: background-color 3s ease;
}
.highlight:hover:before {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  -moz-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: background-color 3s ease;
  transition: background-color 3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="highlight" style="background-image:url(http://cdn2.stillgalaxy.com/ori/2015/06/06/female-doctors-stock-photos-2331433563559.jpg);">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution working fine on both Chrome & Firefox:

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="highlight">
    <div class="filter">
    </div>
    <img src="http://cdn2.stillgalaxy.com/ori/2015/06/06/female-doctors-stock-photos-2331433563559.jpg" alt="image" />
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.highlight {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.highlight .filter {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: background-color 3s ease;
}
.highlight:hover > img{
  transform: scale(1.3);
}
.highlight:hover > .filter {
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}


.highlight img {
  height: 280px;
  transition: transform 3s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In background-size you have to give width otherwise it wont work. 
Check this fiddle i have modified your code :
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shriharim/26Lq1oxx/

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being barely more than a link to an external site is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).