# image scale animation not working with css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a problem: When i add an image in `css` background so image stop scale animation.

Follows HTML Code

```
<ul class="memberList">
   <li class="mem1"><a href="#"><b></b></a> <span>Member Name 1</span></li>
</ul>
```

For full view, please check the [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/epjfpcwa/)

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: when mouse hover image go scale to small with zoom out animation, like when we use in css (scale css property).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background-size transition not work in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879221/background-size-transition-not-work-in-chrome)

Comment: please check Jsfiddle link for full view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doable, you just have to set a `background-size` in `.memberList li.mem1 a b`. Also you may want to move the transition inside that in order to zoom out too. Check this out, it's your code with these two small changes (change the size from `205px 226px` to values that suit your scale preferences):

```css
.memberList{ float: left; margin: 10px 0 0 15px; padding: 0; width: 1200px; position: absolute; top:0; left: 0;}
.memberList li{ float: left; margin: 0 7px; text-align: center; list-style: none;}
.memberList li a{display: block; border: solid 1px #f0f0f0; overflow: hidden; height: 144px; width: 130px; margin-bottom: 15px;}
.memberList li a b {display: block; height: 144px; width: 130px;}
.memberList li.mem1 a b{
 background-image: url(https://s13.postimg.org/y77inuf47/member_pic1.jpg);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-size:205px 226px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease; 
}
.memberList li:hover a b{
 background-size: 100% 100%; /* width and height, can be %, px or whatever. */
}
```

```html
<ul class="memberList">
  <li class="mem1"><a href="#"><b></b></a> <span>Member Name 1</span></li>
</ul>
```